# vector < map, vector>

Tags: c++, vector, map

```
class goods {
    vector<pair< map <string,string>, vector<pair<int , int> >>> good;
public:
    virtual ~goods() = 0 {};

    void setGood(string manufacturer, string good, int day, int month, int year) {
        map <string, string> tmp;
        tmp.insert(manufacturer, good);
        //this->good.push_back(tmp, { day, month, year }, { day, month, year });
        this->good.push_back(make_pair(make_pair("key", "data"), make_pair(1, 2)));
    }
```

не могу добавить значение

Comment: vector<pair< map <string,string>, vector<pair<int , int> >>> good;

Comment: У вас же массив пар, а вы пытаетесь добавить в него что-то непонятное.

Comment: Во-первых, `virtual ~goods() = 0 {}` - уже белиберда. Нельзя в одну строчку объявить функцию как `= 0` и тут же сделать определение. Определение должно делаться отдельно за пределами класса. Во-вторых, `make_pair("key", "data")` не является приемлемым инициализатором для `std::map`. Можно: `this->good.push_back({ { { "key", "data" } } , { { 1, 2 } } });`. В-третьих, `tmp.insert(manufacturer, good);` - бессмыслица. У `std::map` нет такого метода `insert`. `tmp.insert({ manufacturer, good });`

Comment: `virtual ~goods() = 0 {}` - вижуал студия так позволяет.

Comment: @KoVadim: Я знаю, но это не важно. В С++ такой синтаксис не допускается.

Answer (score 6):

Тип элемента вектора = `pair<map<string, string>, vector<pair<int, int>>>`
Следовательно необходимо добавлять значение именно такого типа

```
map<string, string> first_value{ make_pair("key", "value") };
vector<pair<int, int>> second_value{ make_pair(1, 2) };
// обратите внимание, что здесь необходимо использовать скобки инициализации
// {}
good.push_back(make_pair(first_value, second_value));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class goods {
    vector< pair< map<string,string>, vector<int> > > good;
public:
    virtual ~goods() = 0;
    void setGood(const string& manufacturer,
                const string& g, int day, int month, int year) {
        map <string, string> tmp;
        tmp.insert(make_pair(manufacturer, g));
        good.push_back(make_pair(tmp, vector<int>{day, month, year}));
    } 
};
```

Перечислю ваши ошибки:

```
 virtual ~goods() = 0 {};
```

это чистый виртуальный деструктор, у которого не может быть тела (даже пустого). Так что  уберите скобки.

```
tmp.insert(manufacturer, good);
```

`std::map<string, string>`  содержит пары строк, а не две строки

Что касается архитектуры:

Если вы хотите в вектор ввести пару  таблицы и  даты, то вам нужен вектор пар таблиц и вектор с целыми типами, а не вектор пар.
Вообше то, мне думается что вам нужно хранить в классе

`vector< pair< pair<string,string>, vector<int> > >` 
поскольку вы храните там одну пару с датой.

P.S. для читабельности и для того, чтобы избегать случайных ошибок, лучше избегать повторение имен. Или в аргументах или  в приватном поле изменить имя гораздо проще, чем потом следить что есть что. Вообше то приватный член может иметь любое самое короткое имя(клиету класса она всеравно не нужна)

Comment: деструктор не может быть чисто виртуальным.

Comment: с деструктором все правильно. Деструктор базового класса должен быть виртуальным, если деструктор чисто виртуальный тогда он обязательно(!) должен иметь тело, т.к. наследники деконструируют объект и будут вызывать деструктор. Попробуйте объявить чисто виртуальный деструктор без тела - получите ошибку линковки. Об этом писал Скотт Мейерс (Эффективное использование с++, Правило №7), кое-что есть [тут](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm)

Comment: @acade, не знаю почему я не заметил, что это деструктор, но  деструктор обьявить чисто виртуальный  с пустым телом это то же  неправильно...  После вашего замечания я проверил(хоть и  раньше  знал, что это ошибка),  и мой компилятор выдает ошибку. Тогда обьясните пожалуйста, почему мой компилятор выдает ошибку; C:\Users\Mk\Documents\H\C++\test\main.cpp:12: error: pure-specifier on function-definition
     virtual ~goods() = 0 {}
                      ^?

Comment: У любой чистой виртуальной функции может быть тело. А деструктора всегда *должно* быть тело, даже если он чистый виртуальный. Языке С++ запрещается писать определения чистых виртуальных функций прямо в классе. Такие определения должны делаться отдельно, за пределами класса. Ваш компилятор ругается именно на некорректный синтаксис, а не на сам факт наличия тела у чистой виртуальной функции.

Comment: @AnT,  рад вас слышать, но до сих пор я знал обратное: зачем чистой виртуальной функции тело?  Тело чего?  Где смысль чистой виртуальности тогда? И в конце концов почему мой компилятор выдает ошибку? Это что то новое после C++14? Я просто прошу ответить на мои вопросы. Вернее я счас оформлю вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: "Чистая виртуальность" запрещает только *виртуальные вызовы* функции, но никак не влияет на прямые *невиртуальные* вызовы функции. Синтаксис `pointer->ClassName::function()` (т.е. с указанием имени класса) позволяет вам вызвать любую функцию напрямую, в обход виртуальности. Вот для таких вызовов (если они есть в программе) чистой виртуальной функции и нужно тело. Деструктор предка из деструкторов потомков всегда вызывается "напрямую". Поэтому даже если деструктор предка является чистым виртуальным, ему все равно обязательно нужно тело. Так было всегда, с начала времен. С++14 тут ни при чем.